# why can't i simulate protanopia?

Tags: android, kotlin, bitmap

I want to simulate protanopia color blindness.

This is what i want:
[image]

This is the code

```
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == cameraRequest) {
            val photo: Bitmap = data?.extras?.get("data") as Bitmap
            val mutablePhoto = photo.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true)
            val imheight = mutablePhoto.height
            val imwidth = mutablePhoto.width

            val nprotanopia = arrayOf<Float>(0.567F, 0.433F,0F,0F,0F,0.558F,0.442F,0F,0F,0F,0F,0.242F,0.758F,0F,0F,0F,0F,0F,1F,0F,0F,0F,0F,0F,1F)

            fun setN(n: Float): Float {
                return if (n < 0) 0F else if (n < 255) n else 255F
            }

            for (y in 0 until imheight) {
                for (x in 0 until imwidth) {
                    val i = mutablePhoto.getPixel(x, y)

                    Log.d("RI", i.toString())

                    val red: Float = Color.red(i).toFloat()
                    val blue: Float = Color.blue(i).toFloat()
                    val green: Float = Color.green(i).toFloat()
                    val alpha: Float = Color.alpha(i).toFloat()

                    val nR=((red*nprotanopia[0])+(green*nprotanopia[1])+(blue*nprotanopia[2])+(alpha*nprotanopia[3])+nprotanopia[4])
                    val nG=((red*nprotanopia[5])+(green*nprotanopia[6])+(blue*nprotanopia[7])+(alpha*nprotanopia[8])+nprotanopia[9])
                    val nB=((red*nprotanopia[10])+(green*nprotanopia[11])+(blue*nprotanopia[12])+(alpha*nprotanopia[13])+nprotanopia[14])
                    val nA=((red*nprotanopia[15])+(green*nprotanopia[16])+(blue*nprotanopia[17])+(alpha*nprotanopia[18])+nprotanopia[19])

                    val r: Float = setN(nR)
                    val g: Float = setN(nG)
                    val B: Float = setN(nB)
                    val A: Float = setN(nA)

                    Log.d("R", r.toString())

                    mutablePhoto.setPixel(x, y, Color.argb(A, r, g, B))
                }
            }
            imageView.setImageBitmap(mutablePhoto)
        }
    }
```

This is the output:
[image]

I don't know what is wrong. I get the theory from [web archive for protanopia](http://web.archive.org/web/20081014161121/http://www.colorjack.com/labs/colormatrix/)

Comment: I didn't check the theory, but it just looks too bright - you can try to divide the numbers before clipping them to 255 as you do at the beginning... also, why are you changing the Alpha (transparency) layer?

Comment: It can't be right to be adding part of the alpha component to R, G, and B. Alpha will always be 255 for an opaque image, and why should they be related at all?